# Dialogflow - Fulfillment Webhook Response different from Documentation

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-es

I'm currently using Dialogflow in combination with fulfillment/webhooks.

In the [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment) of the fulfillments there is an example POST request for webhooks:

```
POST body:

{
    "contexts": [
                    string
    ],
    "lang": string,
    "query": string,
    "sessionId": string,
    "timezone": string
}
```

The request that I'm receiving on my end is different from what is defined in the documentation. Has somebody an idea why?

This is what I receive:

```
{
    "id": "GUID",
    "timestamp": "2018-01-12T12:25:32.202Z",
    "lang": "de",
    "result": {
        "source": "agent",
        "resolvedQuery": "Test",
        "speech": "",
        "action": "",
        "actionIncomplete": false,
        "parameters": {
            "Nummer": ""
        },
        "contexts": [],
        "metadata": {
            "intentId": "XYZ",
            "webhookUsed": "true",
            "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
            "intentName": "Intent"
        },
        "fulfillment": {
            "speech": "",
            "messages": [{
                "type": 0,
                "speech": ""
            }]
        },
        "score": 0.6700000166893005
    },
    "status": {
        "code": 200,
        "errorType": "success",
        "webhookTimedOut": false
    },
    "sessionId": "GUID"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that different invocation sources send slightly different data to the web hook.

For example the Google Action simulator will send different information in the context reply than say the test pane in an intent.

Im guessing that the answer may lie in where/how your calling the web hook.